# Is there any way to send an email with ignoring the saved email in mail application in ios device?

Tags: xcode, swift

I want to make an app with XCode(SWIFT)and I would like to let the user enter more than one email and their passwords. the app will check either if they are match correctly or not(email and it's password). then, the app will save them in coredata. 
and that will let the user send email by choose any email and type the receiver email then click on SEND the email will go directly.
(I don't want this window)

[Valid XHTML http://postimg.org/image/rlsap8wdh](http://postimg.org/image/rlsap8wdh).

I watched some videos but all of them {the app goes to the email window in an IOS device and send email using the user email that be used in that IOS device}

(I want everything happens here when he choose his email and type the receiver email)

[Valid XHTML http://postimg.org/image/pp7pzk0oz](http://postimg.org/image/pp7pzk0oz).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it.

> Sending emails programmatically, without user intervention, from an
>   iOS application, cannot be implemented using any of the Apple
>   frameworks. It could be possible in a jailbroken phone but then it
>   would never see the inside of App Store.
>
> If you want control of email sending, then a better way would be to
>   set up a web service (at your server end) you can post to using an
>   HTTP request. If you are posting to only one address this can work
>   very well, although you may want to get the user to input their return
>   mail address.
>
> Otherwise only the standard dialog is available (this relies on using
>   whatever account they've setup on the device).

Source : [How to send mail from iphone app without showing MFMailComposeViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427056/how-to-send-mail-from-iphone-app-without-showing-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller)

You can also check following question-answers :

[Alternative ways to send email without UI from ipad or iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12853536/alternative-ways-to-send-email-without-ui-from-ipad-or-iphone)

[Send an email from iOS application without using MFMailCompose UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20272639/send-an-email-from-ios-application-without-using-mfmailcompose-ui)

Comment: Thanks for the information it's helpful @Ashish Kakkad