# PHP Mail_Queue without PEAR

Tags: php, composer-php, pear, bulk-email, mail-queue

I want to send bulk emails and I've found ([Is there a limit when using php mail function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543153/is-there-a-limit-when-using-php-mail-function)) the recommended way is to use PEAR Mail_Queue.
But that question is too old, and I've also read PEAR is almost deprecated and replaced by Composer now.
Is there any alternative to Mail_Queue in Composer? or some other method to send bulk emails with PHP?
* Also is welcome if you can reply as a bonus if Mail_Queue is a PECL extension or a Library, or how to identify that in general.

Comment: I write a queue from structure for beginner if you want u build from structure...https://github.com/diloabininyeri/php-redis-supervisor-queue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can install both `PEAR::Mail` and `PEAR::Mail_Queue` with composer:

```
composer require pear/mail
composer require pear/mail_queue
```

**Edit:**

Packagist says that [Mail_Queue](https://packagist.org/packages/pear/mail_queue) is abandoned, so, I recommend using [Swift Mailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html) as an alternative.

Check [Sending Emails in Batch](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/sending.html#sending-emails-in-batch) to achieve what you want.

Comment: OK, so Mail_Queue is not a PECL extension. Inside packagist it says: "This package is abandoned and no longer maintained. No replacement package was suggested." maybe there is a better option now?

Comment: I see. I edited the answer with an alternative. Hope it helps

Comment: July 2023: Swift Mailer home page delcares that it is EOL as of November 2021. The next package in its evolution is Symfony/Mailer https://symfony.com/doc/current/mailer.html